# Cannot install packages using Visual Studio NuGet Package Manager Console

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, vpn

I have a problem with the Visual Studio 2015 package manager, most probably because the Russian government is trying to block Telegram (but Telegram still work)

```
PM> Install-Package bootstrap
Install-Package : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package bootstrap
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Time Elapsed: 00:03:10.4732173
```

How to solve this? VPN?
Please don't suggest me to live outside of Russia :)

Comment: See: [api.nuget.org IP is blacklisted in Russia :( #5806](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/5806). For myself i resolved problem by writting record `72.21.81.200 api.nuget.org` in the host file.

Comment: @Sandre, Any update for this issue? Could you access to the `nuget.org` now? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: On April 21, I installed the VPN on the Amazon server, next day NuGet became available to me without any tricks

Comment: @Sandre, Sometimes the server `api.nuget.org` will be temporarily unavailable for maintenance or upgrade, we can try to access it later. I will add this possibility to my answer. Since your question is resolved, you can accept it as answer, so we could close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot install packages using Visual Studio NuGet Package Manager Console

Indeed, you will not be able to access the nuget.org when you network is restricted. To solve this problem you need to resolve your network restrictions.

Just as UserName mentioned, you can try to [set `72.21.81.200 api.nuget.org` in hosts file as a workaround](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/5806), `192.16.48.200` and `117.18.232.200` should also work.

Of course, you can try to use VPN to access repositories or host their application on foreign servers that have no problems with connectivity.

Note:

Sometimes the server `api.nuget.org` would be temporarily unavailable for maintenance or upgrade, we can try to access it later.

Hope this helps.